# Floating Point Exception Error

Tags: c++, c

This program compiles fine, but it returns a message "Floating Point Exception" when I run it. I've looked at other threads and the problem appears to be dividing by 0, but I have looked over the program and there's no division by zero in my entire program. I even used the absolute value function in case.

By the way, the program is meant to reduce fractions.

Example input: `6` `12`, representing the fraction `6/12`
Expected output: `1/2`

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*declaring variables*/
int num1, num2, num1b, num2b, gcd, x;
int higher, lower, higher_2, lower_2;

/*declaring functions*/
int find_gcd(int num1, int num2);
void reduce(int numerator, int denominator, int *reduced_numerator, int *reduced_denominator);

int main(void)
{
    do
    {
        printf("enter 2 numbers:  ");
        scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
        reduce(higher, lower, &higher_2, &lower_2);
        printf("enter 0 to end program and any number continue: \n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    } while(x != 0);

    return 0;
}

void reduce(int numerator, int denominator, int *reduced_numerator, int *reduced_denominator)
{
    num1=numerator;
    num2=denominator;

    gcd =find_gcd(numerator, denominator);

    *reduced_numerator = (numerator/abs(gcd));
    *reduced_denominator = (denominator/abs(gcd));

    printf("The GCD is %d/%d\n", *reduced_numerator, *reduced_denominator); 
}

int find_gcd(int m, int n)
{
    while (n != 0) {
        int remainder = m % n;
        m = n;
        n = remainder;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Results from integer divisions may become zero, did you consider this?

Comment: Run in a debugger, and step through the code line by line. If nothing else, the debugger will stop when the exception happens, and let you see where it is, and what the values of involved variables are.

Comment: Use a debugger. You should be able to find the problem without too much difficulty in a debugger.

Comment: Although the problem is easy to see, what do you think the values of the global variables `higher` and `lower` are when you call the `reduce` function? Where do you assign to them?

Comment: Avoid global variables and avoid needless variables (like num1=numerator)

Comment: higher is not num1 and lower not num2

Comment: amongst other problems, the statement: '#include <stdlib.h>' is needed for the 'abs()' function.   Strongly suggest always compiling with all warnings enabled, then fix the warnings. (don' try to hide the warnings).  ( for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')

Comment: the posted code/algorithm does not yield the correct results when the numerator and denominator cannot be evenly divided into each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are not passing your input values `num1` and `num2` into your `reduce()` function. Instead you are passing in the global variables `higher` and `lower`. You didn't assign any values to them, but global variables are always initialized to 0 by default. Therfore, you run into the exception, because in `reduce()` you divide 0 by 0. You can verify that with a debugger.

If I change your `main()` as follows, then your code is at least working for your test case with `6` and `12` as input:

```
int main(void)
{
    do
    {
        printf("enter 2 numbers:  ");
        scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
        reduce(num1, num2, &higher_2, &lower_2);
        printf("enter 0 to end program and any number continue: \n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    } while(x != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> enter 2 numbers:  6
>   12
>   The GCD is 1/2
>   enter 0 to end program and any number continue:

---

As indicated in the comments you should also get rid of global and spurious variables. Therefore, you should first delete the following lines in your code:

```
/*declaring variables*/
int num1, num2, num1b, num2b, gcd, x;
int higher, lower, higher_2, lower_2;
```

Then let your `main()` function start the following way:

```
int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2, higher_2, lower_2, x;
    ...
}
```

And your `reduce()` function should read like this:

```
void reduce(int numerator, int denominator, int *reduced_numerator, int *reduced_denominator)
{
    int gcd = find_gcd(numerator, denominator);

    *reduced_numerator = (numerator/abs(gcd));
    *reduced_denominator = (denominator/abs(gcd));

    printf("The GCD is %d/%d\n", *reduced_numerator, *reduced_denominator); 
}
```

So far, you don't use your variables `higher_2` and `lower_2` in the `main()` function, but I guess you plan to do so. If not, you can also get rid of them together with parameters 3 and 4 of your `reduce()` function.

---

There is another issue with the code you provided (thanks to @user3629249 for pointing it out): You are missing an include for the `abs()` function. So you need to add the line `#include <stdlib.h>` at the beginning of your code (`include <math.h>` will also so the trick, as well as `include <Windows.h>` on Windows).

Comment: Thanks! I have the variables higher_2 and lower_2 in the function call because the function required 4 arguments, and i get an error message when i get rid of them. I'm assuming higher_2 and lower_2 are the 'actual parameter' (i hope i'm using the term correctly) representation of reduced_numerator and reduced_denominator respectively. I very new to programming tho, so there's a good chance my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: @LionelMessi: If you want to get rid of function parameters, then you have to remove them from the function declaration, the function definition, and all places where you are calling the function.